# Twisted setup in Fedora or CentOS

Tags: linux, python-3.x, twisted, fedora

Is there a source tarball of Twisted available for download which could be used to build it in Fedora or CentOS? I see the download for Ubuntu/Debian on the site, of course.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to build from source rather than using the version packaged in Fedora already?

Answer (score 0):

It would be an 'rpm'; Try rpmfind [.net] 
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/secondary/devel/rawhide/src/p/python-twisted-15.4.0-3.fc24.src.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest version of Twisted requires Python 2.7+ because 2.6 support has finally been EOL.  So if you're running an old Python, then I'd suggest you build your own Python 2.7+ and `alt install` it.  It's very important you don't override CentOS's default Python as this could lead to a disastrous situation.  Once Python is updated, then you can do `pip install twisted`.  Alternatively, you could get a yum repo with a updated versions of Python and Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python pip to install twisted in centos or fedora.

Make sure you have python-pip installed then just do `sudo pip install twisted` in terminal